# Referencing previous value in cell (R)

Tags: r, vector, reference, dataframe

I have the following data.frame:

```
head(data.c)

     mark high_mark mark_cum
      5        0        0
      7        1        1
      7        1        2
      NA       0        2
      7        1        3
      7        1        4
```

As there are NAs I need to construct an additional column of normal sequence from 1:length(mark). However, if it is NA vector cell has to take a previous value. So it must look like this:

```
     mark high_mark mark_cum mark_seq
      5        0        0       1 
      7        1        1       2
      7        1        2       3
      NA       0        2       3 
      7        1        3       4
      7        1        4       5
      NA       0        4       5
```

Comment: Why did you `rbind` with an NA row (for mark)? otherwise, `data.c$mark_cum+1`

Comment: But how do I construct `mark_seq`? `data.c$mark_cum+1` doesn't explain the process of creation itself

Comment: I meant `data.c$mark_seq <- data.c$mark_cum+1`  BTW, showing some expected result doesn't mean that you explained how you got the expected output.  Your description was `As there are NAs I need to construct an additional column of normal sequence from 1:length(mark)`  Where is the info about the additional row?

Comment: Aren't you missing a row in your original data set?

Comment: I meant there are NAs in `mark` vector and I need to construct `mark_seq` vector where it will be an ordinary sequence of numbers - but when it is NA in `mark` then `mark_seq` has to take a previous value (or repeat it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) cumsum**  This solution uses the fact that each `mark_seq` element equals the cumulative number of non-NA elements in `mark` at that point.

```
transform(data.c, mark_seq = cumsum(!is.na(mark)))
```

giving:

```
  mark high_mark mark_cum mark_seq
1    5         0        0        1
2    7         1        1        2
3    7         1        2        3
4   NA         0        2        3
5    7         1        3        4
6    7         1        4        5
7   NA         0        4        5


data.c <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

**2) na.locf** Here is a second solution using `seq_along` and `na.locf` (from zoo).  It creates a sequence the same length as the number of non-NA elements in `mark` and uses replace to put them in the spots where the non-NA elements exist.  Then `na.locf` is used to fill in the NAs with the prior values.

```
library(zoo)

transform(data.c, mark_seq=na.locf(replace(mark, !is.na(mark), seq_along(na.omit(mark)))))
```

**3) mark_cum** It was not stated in the question how the input column `mark_cum` is constructed but in the sample output in the question the `mark_seq` column equals the `mark_cum` column plus 1 so if that is always the case then an easy solution is:

```
transform(data.c, mark_seq = mark_cum + 1)
```

**Note:** We used this as the input:

```
Lines <- "mark high_mark mark_cum 
      5        0        0        
      7        1        1       
      7        1        2       
      NA       0        2        
      7        1        3       
      7        1        4       
      NA       0        4"
```

Comment: added additional solutions